# dpkg --list not in sync with apt-get

Tags: apt, dpkg

```
dpkg --list | grep [0-9]\-jre-headless
```

shows,

```
 rc  openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64                         7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1                      amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
rc  openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386                          7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.10.2                      i386         OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
rc  openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64                         8u40~b09-1                                       amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
ii  openjdk-8-jre-headless:i386                          8u40~b09-1                                       i386         OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
```

This clearly says, `openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386` is installed in  my ubuntu 14.04 machine.

However when i run, `apt-get remove openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386`, it says,

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386' is not installed, so not removed
```

Why does `dpkg --list` and `apt-get remove`, show contradictory messages for the same package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dpkg` shown right information, the `rc` flags in its output meaning `openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386` was removed but its configuration files wasn't.

`dpkg -l` is actually front end for `dpkg-query -l`. You can read [dpkg-query manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-query.1.html) for more details.